# 500 Server Connection. Error - Jupyter Lab

Tags: anaconda, jupyter, internal-server-error, jupyter-lab

While trying to launch Jupiter Lab from Anaconda Navigator, I am continuously getting 'Server Connection Error- Invalid Response: 500 Internal Server Error'. Tried some solutions of Issues tracked on Github but nothing works.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0B4p.png)

Below is the Error Description on Anaconda Navigator Pane:

```
[W 23:00:48.600 LabApp] Error loading server extension ipyparallel.nbextension
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/MyName/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1546, in init_server_extensions
mod = importlib.import_module(modulename)
File "/Users/MyName/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ipyparallel'
[I 23:00:48.605 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /Users/MyName/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 23:00:48.605 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /Users/MyName/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab
[W 23:00:48.608 LabApp] JupyterLab server extension not enabled, manually loading...
[I 23:00:48.609 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /Users/MyName/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 23:00:48.609 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /Users/MyName/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab
[I 23:00:48.611 LabApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/MyName
[I 23:00:48.611 LabApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 23:00:48.612 LabApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=8b2eb70aca4d7230313e1ec5178745ea84875981d0482c16
[I 23:00:48.612 LabApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 23:00:48.616 LabApp] 

Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
to login with a token:
http://localhost:8888/?token=8b2eb70aca4d7230313e1ec5178745ea84875981d0482c16
[I 23:00:49.252 LabApp] Accepting one-time-token-authenticated connection from ::1
[W 23:00:49.856 LabApp] Could not determine jupyterlab build status without nodejs
[E 23:00:49.862 LabApp] Uncaught exception GET /api/contents/?content=1&1543561249855 (::1)
HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='GET', uri='/api/contents/?content=1&1543561249855', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/MyName/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1592, in _execute
result = yield result
File "/Users/MyName/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1133, in run
value = future.result()
File "/Users/MyName/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
yielded = next(result)
File "/Users/MyName/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/handlers.py", line 112, in get
path=path, type=type, format=format, content=content,
File "/Users/MyName/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 431, in get
model = self._dir_model(path, content=content)
File "/Users/MyName/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 337, in _dir_model
if self.should_list(name) and not is_file_hidden(os_path, stat_res=st):
File "/Users/MyName/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/utils.py", line 145, in is_file_hidden_posix
stat_res = os.stat(abs_path)
OSError: [Errno 62] Too many levels of symbolic links: '/Users/MyName/config'
[W 23:00:49.870 LabApp] Unhandled error
[E 23:00:49.871 LabApp] {
"Host": "localhost:8888",
"Pragma": "no-cache",
"Accept": "*/*",
"Authorization": "token 8b2eb70aca4d7230313e1ec5178745ea84875981d0482c16",
"Accept-Language": "en-us",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
"Cache-Control": "no-cache",
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0.1 Safari/605.1.15",
"Connection": "keep-alive",
"Referer": "http://localhost:8888/lab",
"Cookie": "username-localhost-8888=\"2|1:0|10:1543561249|23:username-localhost-8888|44:YmRiOThiODMxODA3NDM1NDhmMmNlYjZiMDM2YmFhZWI=|4cec00ae573ce2c242270e1ad51ea5b8bf633143c50175883402000209508f9e\"; username-localhost-8889=\"2|1:0|10:1543560086|23:username-localhost-8889|44:ZmQyNTdmMjU3OTQ4NDg4MjllNWE5MThiMDY4YmMxOTk=|0516e335b3a1b0666b7b03fe9e19820005734c51f9cff9aaa4d19bbe5ac3b72c\"; username-localhost-8890=\"2|1:0|10:1543352001|23:username-localhost-8890|44:MTlkMTFlNGYyNWQ5NDE3NDg0NDk4MTMyMmExMDRhMzY=|1f0e8c67a9bfa9bfe8367f0bc3fef515c76590f21c0f0f26576e466bfa7bd8b6\"; _xsrf=2|d4da0c6c|43dea648c15b852bca19be92af6821cf|1543351994"
}
[E 23:00:49.871 LabApp] 500 GET /api/contents/?content=1&1543561249855 (::1) 13.31ms referer=http://localhost:8888/lab
```

Any Help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I am getting the same error. Did you manage to fix it?